# Why is the custom cursor laggy?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, mouse-cursor

So I am building my website and I decided to use a custom cursor and at first it worked smoothly and all but recently it has started to lag like anything.

I have made a white ring which follow the original cursor and hid the original cursor, ofcourse I achieved this with javascript. At first it worked very nicely and smooth but now its lagging like anything. I am being forced to remove it but I really want it. i thought it was because I had a slow computer but even on a higher end computer it lagged. Please help me what do I do?

Below is my website code.

```js
var typed = new Typed(".auto-type", {
  strings: ["Shaheer Ahmed", "a Thinker", "a Youth", "Shaheer Ahmed  "],
  typeSpeed: 60,
  backSpeed: 60,
  backDelay: 2500,
  startDelay: 1000,
});

// 00 CUSTOM CURSOR 00
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".cursorLrg");
const navlinks = document.querySelectorAll(".cursorLrg");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  let leftPosition = e.pageX + 4;
  let topPosition = e.pageY + 4;

  cursor.style.left = leftPosition + "px";
  cursor.style.top = topPosition + "px";
});

links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    cursor.classList.add("large");
  });
});

links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    cursor.classList.remove("large");
  });
});

// Animation

navlinks.forEach((li, i) => {
  li.style.animationDelay = 0 + i * 140 + "ms";
});

document.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
  var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  cursor.style.opacity = "0";
});
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
  var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
  cursor.style.opacity = "1";
});
// 11 CUSTOM CURSOR 11

const navBtn = document.querySelector(".navBtn");
const navContainer = document.querySelector(".navContainer");
const navContainer2 = document.querySelector(".navContainer2");
const navContainer3 = document.querySelector(".navContainer3");
const navContainer4 = document.querySelector(".navContainer4");

navBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    navContainer.classList.toggle("menuOpen");
    navContainer2.classList.toggle("menuOpen2");
    navContainer3.classList.toggle("menuOpen3");
    navContainer4.classList.toggle("menuOpen4");
  }, 400);
});

const link = document.querySelectorAll(".navContainer a");
```

```css
* {
  cursor: url("img/custom-cursor.png"), auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #000909;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: url("img/custom-cursor.png"), auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mName {
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  color: #e6a623;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 60pt;
  margin: 40px 0 0 65px;
  user-select: none;
}

.auto-type {
  z-index: 0;
}
/* NEED TO EDIT TO MAKE IT CONTENT EDITIBLE AFTER THE ANIMATION IS COMPLETE */

.c1 {
  color: #000909;
}

.c2 {
  color: #e6a623;
}
.ftr-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e6a623;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.lnk-contact {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3.4em;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0.8em 1em 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  border: #000909 solid 3px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000909;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
  user-select: none;
}
.lnk-donate {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0.8em 0 0 1em;
  line-height: 3.7em;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000909;
  color: #e6a623;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out,
    border 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 3px solid #000909;
  border-radius: 10px;
  user-select: none;
}

.ftr-text {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 2.3em 0 0 1em;
}

.lnk-contact:hover {
  background-color: #000909;
  color: #e6a623;
}
.lnk-donate:hover {
  background-color: #e6a623;
  color: #000909;
  border: 3px solid #000909;
}

@keyframes type {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}

/*  00 CUSTOM CURSOR 00 */
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width 1000ms, height 1000ms;
  transition: all ease-out 0.07s;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor.large {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

/* 11 CUSTOM CURSOR 11 */

.navIcon {
  width: 3%;
  height: 5%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 29px;
  right: 26px;
  z-index: 4;
  user-select: none;
}

.navContainer ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menuOpen.navContainer ul li a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 500ms;
  line-height: 130px;
}

.navContainer ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.navContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e6a623;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  clip-path: circle(30px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
  transition: all 800ms ease-in-out;

  z-index: 3;
}

.navContainer.menuOpen {
  clip-path: circle(75%);
}

.navContainer2 {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  clip-path: circle(30px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
  transition: all 700ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navContainer2.menuOpen2 {
  clip-path: circle(75%);
}
.navContainer3 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  clip-path: circle(30px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
  transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navContainer3.menuOpen3 {
  clip-path: circle(75%);
}
.navContainer4 {
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  clip-path: circle(30px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navContainer4.menuOpen4 {
  clip-path: circle(75%);
}

.custom-selection::selection {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Shaheer Ahmed</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"  />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono:wght@200&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/x-icon"
      href="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/branding-identity-corporate-vector-logo-design_460848-8717.jpg?w=2000"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="navBtn" draggable="false"
      ><img
        class="navIcon cursorLrg"
        src="./img/menu.png"
        alt="Menu Icon"
        draggable="false"
    /></a>
    <div class="navContainer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navContainer2"></div>
    <div class="navContainer3"></div>
    <div class="navContainer4"></div>

    <h1 id="mName">
      I am<br /><span class="auto-type" contenteditable="false"></span>
    </h1>

    <footer>
      <div class="ftr-container">
        <a class="lnk-contact cursorLrg" draggable="false" href="#"
          >Contact Me</a
        >
        <a class="lnk-donate cursorLrg" draggable="false" href="./donate.html"
          >Donate</a
        >
        <p class="ftr-text custom-selection">
          Copyright ©Shaheer Ahmed Khan 2023
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.11"></script>
    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
````

Comment: Well, a good thing to do is to control the polling of the mouse move listener. Right now you have no limit, and it polls as high-resolution as it can (based on your device hardware). If you were to slow this polling down a bit, this may stabilize the cursor movement across a variety of devices/os/browser. it would tax the machine less, but to the user they may perceive no change and still have smooth cursor movement. Look into debounce and throttle functions.

Comment: There’s quite a lot of code here. Is it all relevant to the problem? Please try creating a minimal reproducible example. The very act of doing this may highlight why you used to get smoothness and now don’t. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee